# JointJS baseline-shift

Tags: jointjs

I'm using JointJS 3.2.0, and I need to have texts like P<sub>N</sub>=xxx.

How baseline-shift is supposed to be used in JointJS? I tried

```
 markup: '<g><text>\
                <tspan class="left"></tspan>\
                <tspan class="sub"></tspan>\
                <tspan class="right"></tspan>\
                </text></g>',
         attrs: {
                '.sub': {
                'baseline-shift': 'sub',
                },
```

but it creates another tspan inside each tspan which all have dy=0.
Similar approach with  didn't make the correct tspan have the baseline-shift attribute.

I tried another approach where I changed textVerticalAnchor to 'top', but in that case I can't control the spacing between each tspan, and the letters are spaced further apart than just inside one tspan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Text Annotations](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v3.2/vectorizer.html#V.prototype.text) might help here.

```
element.attr('label', {
  text: 'Pn = xxx',
  annotations: [{ start: 1, end: 2, attrs: { 'baseline-shift': 'sub' }}]
});
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kumilingus/ngwa29hv/1/).